# Working with data received via an API on a site (JSON, XML)

Tags: php, database, api, rest

I think it is inefficient to do a request on each page visit to collect the information. I would like to know what the theory of best practises are regarding to working with data that is received from an API.

Should the data be stored in my own database or should I just make a call to the API every time?

As example if I would use Strava to get my running results. Should I just use the result directly from the API or should I store these in a database. And than check after a certain period if there are new or updated results and update my database accordingly?

I have read some articles about RESTful API's but they only give information about how to get, delete, update the data etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are using it for...

If the information is likely not to change and is likely to be reaccessed on your site then store it.

Otherwise just get it from the API, it will always be up to date and it's less code to write if you don't have to store it.

If you are storing it and you know what information you are likely to require you could retrieve in the background at set-intervals.

You can also look at other factors when making your judgement, such as the speed of the API or if you have a API call limit.

You are probably not finding an definitive answer as there isn't one, but I hope this clarifies this for you =]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of Strava or whatever API you will use.

In my case, generally in applications there is a need to keep track of what have been exchanged with an external system, for example to give proof that the data has been read or written.

For this, usually there is something kept in the local database, and usually it does not have to be the track of the complete data exchange.